# Bulk insert in PingDirectotry

Tags: pingfederate

I am trying to create and update bulk records in PingDirectory using REST is there any way we can achieve bulk update and insert. Single insertion is working fine using POST request with Postman

`https://directory.*.com/directory/v1/`

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PingDirectory server doesn't have API endpoints that have support bulk commits. Doing bulk modifications to a running directory server is computationally expensive, due to indexing requirements and the like. While being able to "move faster" in theory if you do a bulk modification in a single batch, we've found that you can achieve the same speeds with parallelism.

Switch to a few parallel modifications running at the same time, or, switch to an `ldapmodify` command with an LDIF.